# Restrict the execution time of a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to restrict the query or stored procedure to execute only for specific time interval.
I am not asking to limit timeout in configuration.

For example:
I want the execute below stored procedures

```
EXEC sp_01 --for 2 minutes
EXEC sp_02 --for 5 minutes
EXEC sp_03 --for 7 minutes
```

After such time interval the SQL Server must stop the execution forcefully.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since your question has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Thank you but.. kindly focus on the question.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir what if for sp_01 it goes beyond 2 minutes should I terminate it also? execution time per stored procedure may vary and many areas should be taken into consideration (logic, how bad your query is, how big is the data and how ambitious you are)

Comment: If the time limit goes beyond the execution process must terminate.

Comment: I have to execute the .bat file via MS SQL query and the .bat file executes the desktop application that runs the specific c# code. master..XP_CMDSHELL This takes many many time to execute but the c# codes works within 2 mints and the query execution continues.
That's the purpose to terminate the query execution.